# Default variable referencing own class in python

Tags: python, default-value

I'm trying to write something like:

```
class MyClass(object):
    @staticmethod
    def test(x, y, z=None):
        if not z:
            z = external_function(MyClass)
```

Is it possible in python to rewrite it to something like:

```
class MyClass(object):
    @staticmethod
    def test(x, y, z=external_function(MyClass)):
        pass
```

(The second code does not work as it is referencing MyClass which is not defined at this point)

Comment: Class methods must have the instance variable (object) `self` as their first variable.  99% of the time, you're not passing the class to an external function, you're passing the instance variable (or object), `self`, to the external function.  What you're doing with the class as a whole, seems incorrect.  Are you trying to write a `@classfunction`?  Or are you trying to manipulate an object of the class?

Comment: It's actually `@staticmethod`.

Comment: Not a fix for your problem, but you should really make `test` a *class*method, which takes `cls` as the first parameter, then use that in your call to `external_function`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to rewrite the code that way. The closest you can do is something like:

```
class MyClass:
      pass

def test(x, y, z=external_function(MyClass):
      pass

MyClass.test = staticmethod(test)
del test
```

Note that this assumes Python 3; in Python 2, you may need to fiddle around with the `new` module. But though this is possible, the intention of the code is very non-obvious. It is better to stick to `if z is None`, or to refactor your code to not need this.

Comment: Unfortunately it is python 2 (2.5 or 2.6)

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible, since whatever is in the argument definition of any method, be it a static method or a normal method, is parsed and executed at class creation time, before the class object that you try to use has been created. Defaults are also evaluated at this time, as the code below demonstrates.

```
def say_hi():
    print "Getting default value"

class MyClass(object):
    print "Creating class"
    @staticmethod
    def test(a=say_hi()):
        print "test called"

MyClass.test()
MyClass.test()
```

Output:

```
Creating class
Getting default value
test called
test called
```